# How to move related products at very bottom of product page?

Tags: magento2.3, related-products

I want to display the related products at very bottom of the product page. How can I move it?

Can anyone please explain me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Related products show in `content.aside` container, which is render after `content` container.

Both `content.aside` and `content` comes in `main` container, So you can move related product after `main` container.

You can use `page.bottom.container` for moving, use following code in

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="page.bottom.container" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks so much. Its working

Comment: Welcome @Siva :)